# Python multiprocessing, не передается значение переменной из одной функции в другую

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Пытаюсь разобраться с мультипроцессингом, но никак не пойму как правильно его использовать в моем случае, может кто подскажет.

Итак, есть 3 функции: `stream`, `print_sound` - прослушка микрофона и детектор громкости, если громкость есть то она суммируется и `one` которая печатает все время сумму громкости, вот только  она не печатает, вывод идет все время 0, хотя если принт написать в `print_sound`, то все нормально суммируется и выводится.

Подскажите, почему так, и как пофиксить?

PS: изучаю python месяц

Код ниже:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import keyboard
import time as t
import pyautogui
import multiprocessing

r=0
rr = 0

def one():
    try:
        while True:
            print(rr)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('1')

def stream():
    global st
    with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
        sd.sleep(1000000)

def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    global rr
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    r = int(volume_norm)
    rr = rr+r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=stream)
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=one)
    p1.start()
    p3.start()
    p1.join()
    p3.join()
```

Comment: А особо никак, однако... Я в свое время на Threads отвалился, так и не нашел вменяемо как это сделать, чтобы мультипроцессинг обменивались информацией напрямую... Но это все ИМХО, буду рад если кто то сможет написать как.
PS Глобал переменные там точно не помогут, они идут глобалами только в пределах 1 процесса, для каждого следующего будет заводиться полностью новый свой набор. И еще, возможно я не прав, но у тебя где p1.join() он его выполнит, и пока у тебя p1 сам не завершится join p3 не сработает. Но это вот вообще не точно. PPS можно .txt или бд сделать для передачи, но это явно не то...

Comment: Да, у разных процессов - разная память (копия памяти на момент отпочкования процесса). Попробуйте использовать потоки вместо процессов. И лучше использовать специальные объекты (всякие там мьютексы, семафоры и т.п.) для передачи информации даже между потоками, а не глобальные переменные. Из-за оптимизаций и прочего изменения в обычных переменных могут сразу не увидеться разными потоками, а вот специальные объекты для синхронизации потоков должны работать правильно.

Comment: Вы можете объяснить словами что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: "но у тебя где p1.join() он его выполнит, и пока у тебя p1 сам не завершится join p3 не сработает" - сработает, все функционирует. 
Решение есть, спасибо всем за комментарии.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

У каждого процесса - своя память. Это означает, что у каждого процесса своя копия переменной `rr`. Когда один процесс ее модифицирует (у себя в памяти), другой этого не видит, он видит то значение, которое переменная получила в момент запуска (при старте процесса идет загрузка модулей и переменные получают начальные значения) или работы процесса.

Для того, чтоб можно было обмениваться данными между процессами, нужно использовать специальные механизмы межпроцессного взаимодействия, представленные утилитами из модуля `multiprocessing`.

### Managers

Менеджеры позволяют создавать переменные, которые разделяются между процессами. Поддерживаются:

- просто значение - `Manager.Value`
- словарь `Manager.dict`
- список `Manager.list`
- и др.

Если говорить грубо и упрощенно, то при изменении переменной менеджер заботится о том, чтоб значение синхронизировалось с другими процессами.

Пример использования `Manager.Value`:

```
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing

def watcher(var):
    while True:
        print(f'watcher: {var.value}')
        sleep(0.3)

def modifier(var):
    for i in range(5):
        var.value += 1
        print(f'modifier: modified {var.value}')
        sleep(1)
    print(f'modifier: done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    var = manager.Value('var', 0)
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=modifier, args=(var,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=watcher, daemon=True, args=(var,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
```

### Очереди и каналы

[Позволяют](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) посылать однонаправленный (Queue) и двунаправленные (Pipe) потоки данных между процессами.

Пример использования `multiprocessing.Queue`:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def producer(queue):
    for i in range(1, 5):
        queue.put(i)
        print(f"producer: put {i}")
        sleep(1)
    queue.put(None)  # посылаем сигнал окончания
    print("producer: done")

def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        print(f"consumer: get {item}")
    print("consumer: done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=producer, args=(queue,))
    p2 = Process(target=consumer, daemon=True, args=(queue,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    print("main: done")
```

Пример использования `multiprocess.Pipe`:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def ping_pong(name, pipe, initiate):
    if initiate:
        print(f'{name}: sent 1')
        pipe.send(1)
    while True:
        val = pipe.recv()
        print(f'{name}: received {val}')
        if val > 5:
            break
        val += 1
        sleep(1)
        pipe.send(val)
        print(f'{name}: sent {val}')
    print(f"{name}: done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    end1, end2 = Pipe()
    p1 = Process(target=ping_pong, daemon=True, args=('ping', end1, True))
    p2 = Process(target=ping_pong, daemon=True, args=('pong', end2, False))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    while p1.is_alive() and p2.is_alive():
        sleep(1)
    print("main: done")
```

### Решение для задачи из вопроса

Для решение задачи из вопроса удобно поспользоваться `Manager.Value`:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

def one(rr):
    while True:
        print(rr.value)

def stream(rr):
    global st
    with sd.Stream(callback=partial(print_sound, rr)):
        sd.sleep(1000000)

def print_sound(rr, indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    r = int(volume_norm)
    rr.value += r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    rr = manager.Value('rr', 0)
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=stream, args=(rr,))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=one, args=(rr,))
    # ... тут все как раньше
```

Comment: Зачем при использовании процессов, глобальные переменные?

Comment: @Александр В каком смысле "зачем"? Глобальные переменные (как и локальные) это инструмент. Нужно в конкретном случае - используйте, не нужно - не используйте.

Comment: Ну вот вы используете global st вы собираетесь получать значение st в разных процессах? И изменять его в разных процессах?

Comment: @Александр это пример на основе кода из вопроса. Зачем там глобальная переменная - вопрос к автору. К сути вопроса про передачу данных между потоками это не имеет отношения. Эта переменная (как и любая другая глобальная) не будет доступна процессам, у каждого своя копия, как я написал в ответе.

Comment: На всякий случай добавил общих примеров, чтоб не возникало вопросов

Comment: Сам код намного больше, просто я для создания вопроса просмотрел st, в данном примере оно не нужно(тянется из основного кода). manager - попробую, спасибо за решение!