# Ошибка name x is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот

Следующий код выдаёт ошибку `NameError: name 'content_list' is not defined`, при попытке отправки сообщения:

```py
bot.send_message('id', random.choice(content_list))
```

В чём проблема? Полный код ниже:

```py
import telebot
import time
import conf
import datetime
from multiprocessing import *
import schedule
import random
from typing import List
API_TOKEN = conf.TOKEN
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


def start_process():  # Запуск Process
    p1 = Process(target=P_schedule.start_schedule, args=()).start()
    # Откроем файл для чтения
    global content_list
    while True:
        phrases = open("phrases.txt", "r")
        content_list = phrases.readlines()


class P_schedule():  # Class для работы с schedule
    def start_schedule():  # Запуск schedule
        ######Параметры для schedule######
        schedule.every().day.at("12:21").do(P_schedule.send_message1)
        schedule.every(1).minutes.do(P_schedule.send_message2)
        ##################################

        # Запуск цикла
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

    # Функции для выполнения заданий по времени

    def send_message1():
        bot.send_message('id', random.choice(content_list))

    def send_message2():
        bot.send_message('id', random.choice(content_list)
    ################

###Настройки команд telebot#########


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']))
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нажали start')
#####################
```

Comment: У вас `content_list` существует только в главном процессе, при использовании `p1 = Process(target=P_schedule.start_schedule, args=()).start()` будет создан отдельный процесс, в котором выполнится функция, но у нее должен быть контекст. Например, передайте явно в функцию `content_list`. Или используйте потоки, у них общая видимость переменных

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python multiprocessing, не передается значение переменной из одной функции в другую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305346/python-multiprocessing-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83)