# Логика взаимодействия в Condition - Wait и Notify. Почему не работает, как ожидается?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Отладочный пример выдаёт не то, что ожидаю. Вероятно, не понимаю полностью логику wait и notify. Ниже ожидаемые и получаемые  из PуCharm результаты с рядом комментариев + код. Просьба пояснить, что не так. Полезные советы по поумнению тоже принимаются с благодарностью.

***Что ожидается от скрипта:***

Процесс reader бесконечно печатает сочетание ("хотим это печатать" + 10 раз "и печатаем это"), бесконечно рассылая снятие блокировки процессу writer. Writer регулярно печатает сочетание ("condition" + "и тут дождались").

***Что получается (описание):***

Процесс writer1 зависает на строке cond.wait(), вероятно, не получив cond.notify от процесса reader.  Почему процесс reader не посылает в цикле 10 раз cond.notify  - не ясно. Вероятно, застревает на первом же.
PуCharm выдает ряд предупреждений вокруг cond.notify, но я их смысл не могу нагуглить, логика же работы методов Python в synchronize.py, например, пока не понятна. Смысл lock is not owned в данном контексте тоже не ясен.

***Что получается (экран):***

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()

  File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Serge\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 10, in reader
    cond.notify ()  #что-то не так 

  File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\synchronize.py", line 271, in notify
    assert self._lock._semlock._is_mine(), 'lock is not owned'

AssertionError: lock is not owned

хотим это печатать

и печатаем это

зашли сюда

condition
```

***Код:***

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Condition
import time

def reader(cond):
    while True:
        print('хотим это печатать')
        for x in range (10):
            print('и печатаем это')
            cond.notify ()  #что-то не так 
            print('но не печатаем даже это')
            time.sleep(1)


def writer1(cond):
    print('зашли сюда')
    with cond:
        print('condition')
        cond.wait()              #зависаем здесь?
        print('и тут дождались') #не печатается эта строка

if __name__ == '__main__':
    condition = Condition()
    new_process = Process(target=reader, args=(condition,))
    new_process.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    new_process1 = Process(target=writer1, args=(condition,))
    new_process1.start()
```

Comment: Попробуй добавить функций reader врт это with cond:

Comment: @СергейШашко ,  прошу прощения, но вообще не понял совет - каких функций добавить, и что за "врт это with cond:"?

Comment: уже дали ответ. :)

Comment: частичный пока:-), чего-то ещё не понимаю.

Comment: К сожалению я тоже, инфы как кот наплакал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтоб и ждать и посылать уведомления с помощью `Condition` нужно сначала захватить блокировку ассоциированную с этим `Condition`.

При ожидании вы это делаете:

```
with cond:
   ...
   cond.wait()
```

Нужно то же самое делать и при уведомлении:

```
with cond:
    cond.notify ()  #что-то не так
```

Еще не хватает ожидания в конце:

```
    new_process.join()
    new_process1.join()
```

Без этого главный поток выходит и хотя запущенные процессы остаются, созданный `Condition` может быть не совсем в рабочем состоянии, т.к. он уже вышел из области видимости. Особенно это видно во втором процессе из-за того, что второй процесс стартует с задержкой. `multiprocess.Condition` использует файл для хранения какой-то информации, и при завершении основного скрипта, файл очевидно удаляется и второй процесс не может получить свой параметр.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно с lock is not owned.  Но ответ снял только первую часть проблемы. Цикл с notify заработал после замены "while True:" на "with cond:", но это не помогло  - "и тут дождались" не печатается.

Comment: Вообще, необходимость захвата Condition  означает, что моя идея решить задачу с одним процессом  (reader), заполняющим FIFO буфер (Queue), и тремя (writer1, 2 и 3), забирающими из него информацию (одна чать информации берётся один раз одним, а не всеми тремя - аналог ситуации с материальными объектами), когда reader не блокирует writers, не сработает и надо что-то другое использовать. То ли Event, то ли вообще не сигналить из reader, пусть writers сами смотрят, пуст ли буфер. Подумаю.

Comment: Если нужна очередь, то лучше использовать [готовые решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1305352/218971), а именно `multiprocessing.Queue` или `Pipe`, а не эти низкоуровневые примитивы. Что касается notify, то тут видно, что есть проблема с запуском процесса, но пока не ясно в чем она. Пример, вроде выглядит правильно, как разберусь - напишу.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: 1) Спасибо, но у меня всё без изменений. После печати "condition" - висит (относительно кода выше - заменил "while True:" на "with cond:" + в  самый конец добавил эти два join копипастом). 
И я хотел бесконечные процессы, join не это подразумевает.
Но вопрос теоретический, так делать без этого теперь буду,вероятно. Просто интересно.
2) Я и использовал Queue (просто из примера отладочного убрал), но пытался её c Condition объединить, так как хотел, чтобы к пустой очереди не обращались writers,а ждали сигнала. На всякий случай, multiprocessing.Queue и Queve - одно и то же в данном случае же?

Comment: В дополнение: мою фразу выше "И я хотел бесконечные процессы, join не это подразумевает." просьба игнорировать. Она неверная относительно роли join.

Comment: Вот модифицированный ваш код, который работает https://paste.in/g3GybB. Про Queue я дал ссылку выше с полностью рабочим примером. Совмещать condition и queue вообще нет смысла, реализация Queue внутри ждет и синхронизация и уведомления там уже встроенные.

Comment: Да, верно, спасибо большое. Я цикл не модифицировал, чтобы condition выставлялся столько же раз, сколько notify посылался - в этом ошибка. И да, рабочий пример я видел, спасибо, потому и написал, что "вопрос теоретический".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135439/discussion-between--and-roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua).