# Многопоточная работа с единственным объектом

Tags: python, многопоточность

У меня есть Класс по которому я создаю объект и хочу совершить параллельную работу по вызову одного и того же метода.

Вот моя упрощенная реализация:

```
import multiprocessing
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def sum(self, num):
        self.a += num
        return self.a
    def multi_sum(self, sum_list):
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            res = pool.map(self.sum,sum_list)
        print(self, res)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = A()
    x.multi_sum(range(1,10)
```

Как я понял, каждый процесс создает копию начального объекта и модифицирует ее.

Как мне сделать так чтобы каждый процесс модифицировал первоначальный объект и передавал его дальше?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python multiprocessing, не передается значение переменной из одной функции в другую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305346/python-multiprocessing-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83)

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно поменять одну строчку, но только если у вас питон `3.7` или позднее:

```py
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
                     ^^^^^^
```

На вот эту:

```py
with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool() as pool:
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Тогда будут использоваться **потоки** вместо **процессов** и поведение будет такое, как вы хотите - будет меняться один объект, а не его копии в разных процессах.

Но помните про `GIL`, толку от такой многопоточности может быть не так много, как вам хотелось бы.

Comment: я нашел этот метод в документации но оно мне пишет что **AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'pool'** это же встроенная библиотека так? как такое возможно?

Comment: @Honeyloy А какая версия питона у вас? Я так понимаю, если младше чем 3.7, то его и правда там нет.

Comment: Я таки обновил питон до последней версии, он все равно не находит **multiprocessing.pool**

Comment: Ну у вас может быть несколько пионов. Вы уверены что смотрите именно в том, который обновили? Проверьте версию