# Глобальные переменные не сохраняются (два модуля плюс файл config)

Tags: python, переменные, модули

Не получается передать переменную их одного модуля в другой. Одно из решений нашел - это передача переменной через сохранение в фале `config.py`. Но и так не получается.
Эти три файла - примерное моделирование, как в моем проекте. Но результат получается точно такой же. Поэтому, решение, скорее всего, будет одинаковое.

Три файла:

Первый: first.py

```py
import second

def search_form():
    city = 'New York'
    second.parser_fotos(city)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_form()
```

Второй: second.py

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import config

def parser_fotos(city):
    config.city = city
    pool_handler()

def pool_handler():
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(get_person_info, range(3))
    print(config.city)

def get_person_info(lst):
    print(config.city, lst)
```

Третий: config.py

```py
city = 'San Francisco'
```

В функции `get_person_info` печатает *San Francisco* (из `config.py`). А надо *New York*. А вот в `pool_handler` - *New York*. Но мне нужен результат в этой функции - `get_person_info`.
Прошу помощи.

Comment: А что мешает через pool.map передать не один аргумент в функцию get_person_info, а несколько? Дело в том, что multiprocessing.pool запускает отдельные процессы, в принципе и тут можно что-то придумать, но проще делать по нормальному, то есть передавать аргументы в явном виде.

Comment: Я так уже пробовал сделать. Но у меня не получилось. map работает с функцией и итерабельным объектом. Поэтому, в лоб добавить еще один аргумент не получилось к функции map. Да и pool ругается.

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать шину, или редис

Comment: Что такое шина?

Comment: Попробуйте что-то типа pool.map(get_person_info, zip(range(3), [config.city]*3)) только и функция должна два аргумента принять уметь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глобальные переменные не сохраняются, потому что они у каждого процесса свои. При старте нового процесса происходит инициализация переменных заново. Это легко можно увидеть, если добавить `print("init")` в `config.py`.

Читайте еще подробности [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305346/python-multiprocessing-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83/1305352#1305352)

Конкретно эту проблему можно исправить передавая параметр явно, например, используя `partial`:

```
# second.py
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import config


def parser_fotos(city):
    pool_handler(city)


def pool_handler(city):
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(partial(get_person_info, city), range(3))
    print(config.city)


def get_person_info(city, lst):
    print(city, lst)
```