# Как модифицировать член класса в multiprocessing.Pool.map?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Я пытаюсь распараллелить множественные вычисления численными методами. Есть функция, которая принимает скалярные значения `x1`, `x2` и вычисляет значение функции в этой точке. Значение функции необходимо найти в множестве точек. Поэтому я попытался разбить эти вычисления по ядрам.

Попытка №1. Создана функция `calcSingle`, которая рассчитывает значение функции в заданной точке и сохраняет его в массиве - члене класса. Создана функция `calc`, которая формирует сетку исходных данных и запускает многоядерный расчёт с помощью `multiprocessing.Pool.map`.

```
class Solver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mesh = np.zeros(0)

    def calcSingle(self, *l):
        (index, num), = l
        self.mesh[index] = num

    def calc(self):
        self.x1, self.x2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1, 5), np.arange(5, 15))
        self.mesh = np.zeros(self.x1.shape)
        p = Pool(4)
        p.map(self.calcSingle, zip(np.ndindex(self.mesh.shape), itertools.count(1)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solver = Solver()
    solver.calc()
    print(solver.mesh)
```

Этот код выводит массив нулей. Вероятно, когда функция `calcSingle` вызывается в отдельном процессе, `self` ссылается уже на какой-то другой объект. Возможно, это происходит потому, что `multiprocessing.Pool` повторно импортирует текущий модуль для каждого процесса. Тогда я стал искать информацию о передаче аргументов в функцию по ссылке. Такого, как оказалось, в Питоне нет, но есть рекомендации, что можно заворачивать требуемый аргумент в класс с одним атрибутом. По сути, класс `Solver` и есть таковой класс, так почему бы не передать его в функцию `calcSingle`?

Попытка №2.

```
class Solver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mesh = np.zeros(0)

    def calcSingle(self, *l):
        (index, num, obj), = l
        obj.mesh[index] = num

    def calc(self):
        self.x1, self.x2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1, 5), np.arange(5, 15))
        self.mesh = np.zeros(self.x1.shape)
        p = Pool(4)
        p.map(self.calcSingle, zip(np.ndindex(self.mesh.shape), itertools.count(1), itertools.repeat(self)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solver = Solver()
    solver.calc()
    print(solver.mesh)
```

Этот код порождает неконтролируемое количество процессов. Почему - не понимаю.

Конечно, можно заметить,  что функция `map` возвращает `list` значений, возвращённых целевой функцией, и из него можно потом создать массив требуемой структуры. Но интересует именно модификация уже имеющегося массива, так как он может быть и `memmap`.

Comment: чтобы модифицировать переменную разными процессами, она должна лежать в общей памяти и объявляться специальным образом. все, что вы объявляете здесь - на чтение или в области видимости отдельного процесса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python multiprocessing, не передается значение переменной из одной функции в другую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305346/python-multiprocessing-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83)

Comment: Правильнее всё-таки возвращать результат из функции, на которую вы мапите, и обрабатывать этот результат в основном треде. Т.е. `for result in p.map(...):` и что-то делать с `result`. Вообще тут зависит от того, много ли вам данных нужно передать в процесс и обратно. Если много, то тогда лучше иметь объект, который виден всем процессам и умеет в мультипроцессность и работать с ним. А если данных передаётся мало, то правильнее не иметь таких объектов, а просто возвращать результат через `return` и обрабатывать его.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, не получилось обернуть numpy-массив в `Manager.Array` и `Manager.Value`. Возможно, что-то делал не так, но своё решение привёл ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Массивы numpy нельзя сделать разделяемыми между процессами с возможностью записи. Вместо этого можно создать разделяемый C-массив требуемого размера и каждый раз в новом процессе создавать numpy-массив, указав ему в качестве буфера данных разделяемый массив. Тогда данные, которые программа будет записывать в numpy-массив, окажутся в разделяемом C-массиве, и исходный процесс сможет их увидеть.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, RawArray
from ctypes import c_double
import numpy as np
import itertools

class Solver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mesh = np.zeros(0)

    @staticmethod
    def processInit(arr, shape):   # Не может быть приватным
        global ndarray_shared
        ndarray_shared = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=float, buffer=arr)

    @staticmethod
    def calcSingle(*l):     # Не может быть приватным
        (index, num), = l
        ndarray_shared[index] = num

    def calc(self):
        x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1, 5), np.arange(5, 15))
        # Создаём C-массив в разделяемой памяти
        self.shared = RawArray(c_double, x1.size)
        # И на его основе создаём numpy-массив
        self.mesh_shared = np.ndarray(x2.shape, dtype=float, buffer=self.shared)

        with Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count(), initializer=Solver.processInit, initargs=(self.shared, self.mesh_shared.shape)) as p:
            p.map(Solver.calcSingle, zip(np.ndindex(x1.shape), itertools.count(1)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solver = Solver()
    solver.calc()
    print(solver.mesh_shared)
```